# create negative texture in glsl

Tags: opengl, image-processing

I am trying to implement some simple image processing in glsl like creating a gray and negative texture from an image but it seems I can't figure out why this doesn't work in the fragment shader. Style 2 which should  turn the picture into gray works as intended but style 3 which should create a negative image just render a blank image.

```
#version 140

in  vec2 textureCoords;
out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D guiTexture;
uniform int style;

void main(void)
{
    if(style==1)
    {
        out_Color = texture(guiTexture,textureCoords);
    }
    else if(style==2)
    {
        out_Color = texture(guiTexture,textureCoords);
        float grayscale = (out_Color.x+out_Color.y + out_Color.z)/3;
        out_Color = vec4(grayscale,grayscale,grayscale,out_Color.w);
    }
    else if(style==3)
    {
        out_Color = texture(guiTexture,textureCoords);
        float Newr = (255.0 - out_Color.x);
        float Newg = (255.0 - out_Color.y);
        float Newb = (255.0 - out_Color.z);
        out_Color =vec4( Newr, Newg, Newb , out_Color.w);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the shader code, colors are floating point values in the range [0.0,1.0]. It has to be `float Newr= (1.0 - out_Color.x)` ...

Comment: thx a lot for helping me